# Fundamental theorem of calculus of Banach-space valued functions

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow E$ be a  continuous function from the interval $[a,b]$ to a Banach space $E$. Let $F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)\text{ }dt$ where the integral is the Bochner integral. I have to prove that $F'(x)=f(x)$. The first thing I tried to do was try to calculate $F(x+h)-F(h)=\int_x^{x+h}f(t)\text{ }dt$. If $F'(x)=f(x)$ then this integral must equal $hf(x)+o(|h|)$, but the only thing I can say about this integral is $||\int_x^{x+h}f(t)\text{ }dt||_E\leq h||f||_{\infty}$. I am kind of stuck. I need a hint. Thanks.

Comment: $\Bigl\Vert h^{-1}\int_x^{x+h} f(t)\, dt-f(x)\Bigr\Vert\le h^{-1}\int_x^{x+h}\Vert f(t)-f(x)\Vert\, dt$. So if you can show the right hand side of this inequality tends to $0$ as $h\rightarrow0$, you'll have your result.

Comment: @DavidMitra I dont understand how you can pull the $f(x)$ in to the integral: $\int_x^{x+h}f(t)dt-f(x)=\text{lim}_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum[\Delta t\cdot f_n(t_i)]-f(x)=\text{lim}_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum[\Delta t\cdot f_n(t_i)-\frac{f(x)}{n}]=\text{lim}_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum[\Delta t \cdot(f_n(t_i)-\frac{f(x)}{nh}]=\int_x^{x+h}f(t)-\frac{f(x)}{nh}dt$ where $\text{lim}_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n=f$. I know I have done something wrong, because the $n$ should disappear, but I dont see how it should disappear.

Comment: $f(x)={1\over h}\int_x^{x+h} f(x) \,dt$. Note $f(x)$ is a constant here.

Comment: @DavidMitra thanks, I see it now. But do you see why my calculation is wrong?

Comment: I think: After the second equality, the "$1/n$" is your $\Delta t$ (taking a uniform partition). So after the third equality, you want "$\Delta t f(x)$", not "$f(x)/(nh)$".

Answer (score 1):

Proposition A.2.3 of this [document](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm:978-3-540-70781-3/1.pdf) has a proof for that result

Answer (score 0):

See also the proof of Proposition A.2.3 in the book of Röckner https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-22354-4

Answer (score 0):

For $t\in (a,b)$ you have $\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0^+} \left\|h^{-1}{\int\limits_t^{t+h}f(s)-f(t)ds}\right\|_{E}\leq \lim\limits_{h\rightarrow 0^+}\sup\limits_{|s-t|\leq h}\|f(t)-f(s)\|_{E}=0$ since $f$ is continous and on the right hand side you have the modulus of continuity!

Comment: Youre question becomes interesting if you omit the continuity condition!